speed up by multiple rsync at the same time
I am doing rsync command over internet.
however rsync is a bit slow ,and when I use multiple rsync total speed is faster.
So I made this script.
import subprocess

cmd = "ssh root@my.hopto.org ls /media/"
output = subprocess.run(cmd,shell=True, capture_output=True, text=True).stdout

arr = output.splitlines()

for a in arr:
    print(a)

for i,a in enumerate(arr):
    if i > 5: 
        break
    cmd = 'rsync --partial --append --progress -av root@my.hopto.org:"/media/{}" ./test/'.format(a)
    print(cmd)
    subprocess.run(cmd,shell=True)

My purpose is doing five rsync in parallel.
However this script stops only one rsync, then I try
cmd = 'nohup rsync --partial --append --progress -av root@my.hopto.org:"/media/{}" ./test/ &'.format(a)

However each 5 rsync is on the list of ps but not work.
ps aux | grep rsync

 7097   0.0  0.0 408923232   2832 s010  T     6:45PM   0:00.02 rsync --partial --append --progress -av -e ssh -p 17441 root@my.hopto.org..............
.
.
.

Is there any good idea or alternative way to speed up rsync?

I would write code which runs one rsync and later use bash to run it many times using & to run them in background

to run many subprocess.run() at the same time you may have to use threading or multiprocessing. Or you may have to use subprocess.popen() which doesn't wait for end of process.
